# Can't upgrade packages

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

In Debian 9 Thunderbird installed from experimental. Pin priorities set as below:

```
Package: thunderbird* lightning
Pin: release n=sid
Pin-Priority: 1100

Package: *
Pin: release n=stretch-backports
Pin-Priority: 400

Package: *
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 300

Package: *
Pin: release n=sid
Pin-Priority: 200

Package: *
Pin: release a=experimental
Pin-Priority: 50
```

---

```
apt-cache policy thunderbird:

Installed: 1:52.2.0-1
Candidate: 1:52.2.1-3
Version table:
 1:52.2.1-3 1100
    200 http://ftp.pl.debian.org/debian sid/main amd64 Packages
*** 1:52.2.0-1 100
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 1:45.8.0-3 500
    500 http://ftp.pl.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
    300 http://ftp.pl.debian.org/debian testing/main amd64 Packages
```

and the same for **lightning** and **thunderbird-l10n-pl**

There is newer version in sid now but when I try to upgrade (**apt-get dist-upgrade**):

```
The following packages have been kept back:
lightning thunderbird-l10n-pl
```

apt-cache policy :

```
thunderbird -> 1:52.2.1-3 with priority 1100
```

How to upgrade package installed from another repository ?

Comment: Your pinning isn't working correctly. On the assumption that apt applies those pins in order, try moving the thunderbird stanza to the end. I could check this, but I'm too lazy, and its easy enough to test. Also, you've got multiple packages listed after `Package:` in the thunderbird stanza. I don't know if that works. If it still doesn't try dividing them into separate stanzas.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I have just moved thunderbird at the end as alone package and tested with different file in /etc/apt/preferences.d/ still the same. Package position is irrelevant.

Comment: I'm confused by your edit: `apt-cache policy : thunderbird -> 1:52.2.1-3 with priority 1100`. Your output shows 200 earlier.

Comment: @FaheemMitha 200 is globally for sid. 1100 is specific for Thunderbird

Comment: No, I mean your output for `apt-cache policy thunderbird` has `200` for `1:52.2.1-3`. Which is contradicted by `apt-cache policy : thunderbird -> 1:52.2.1-3 with priority 1100`. Though I'm not sure what you mean by that latter text.

Comment: Ok nevermind, why it is not upgrading looks like it should ?

Comment: "There is newer version in sid now but when I try to upgrade :" Please include the exact command you typed. And please replace your `apt-cache policy thunderbird` output with the output of `apt-cache policy thunderbird lightning thunderbird-l10n-pl`.